# JOIN on multiple fields between 2 Tables. How to determine which field caused the join to fail?

Tags: sql, join, view, left-join

I have the following SQL Server query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.wc, 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.loc, 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.ord_no, 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.ser_lot_no, 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.line, 
    ISNULL(dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.ItemNo, '') AS ItemNo, 
    ISNULL(dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.BldSeqNo, '') AS BldSeqNo, 
    ISNULL(dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.BldOrdNo, '') AS BldOrdNo, 
    ISNULL(dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.StringItemNo, '') AS StringItemNo, 
    ISNULL(dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.StringSerLotNo, '') AS StringSerLotNo, 
    MAX(dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.InsertDateTime) AS LatestDateTime, 
    MIN(ISNULL(dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.erp_transaction_id, 0)) AS MinimumErpID, 
    ISNULL(dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.QtyOnHand, 0) AS QtyOnHand
FROM            
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil 
        ON  dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.ser_lot_no = dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.SerLotNo 
        AND dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.ord_no = dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.OrderNo 
        AND dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.line = dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.Bin
WHERE        
    ( dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.erp_transaction_id < 3 OR dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.erp_transaction_id IS NULL ) 
    AND (dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.wc <> '') 
    AND (dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.loc <> '') 
    AND (dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.line <> '')
GROUP BY 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.wc, 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.loc, 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.ord_no, 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.ser_lot_no, 
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.line, 
    dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.ItemNo, 
    dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.BldSeqNo, 
    dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.BldOrdNo, 
    dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.StringItemNo, 
    dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.StringSerLotNo, 
    dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil.QtyOnHand
ORDER BY dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data.ord_no DESC
```

It contains a Left Outer Join between the two tables on 3 fields. Based on the current construction if any of the 3 Joined fields in the right table (dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil) are null or missing then the fields in the left query should return null.

How do I determine which of the 3 fields is the field that caused the join to fail? I would like to differentiate these from each other. Thanks.

(Ex. ser_lot_no and ord_no exists but bin is null vs bin and ord_no exist but ser_lot_no is null. )

Comment: Without knowing preconditions for the data its impossible:
Imagine (a,b,c) in the left table and (a,d,c),(e,b,c) in the right, Which field is the failing?

Comment: @Turo That is what I'm trying to figure out, there shouldn't be a precondition. (a,b,c) in left table and (a,b,c) in right table. They are joined via LEFT JOIN.  If a, b and c show up blank in the left table it is because either a,b or c in the right table was null or didn't match.  I'm trying to figure out which of a, b or c caused the match to fail.

Comment: You should simplify your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You might consider doing this in a new question.

Comment: Joins do not "fail". Any two tables can be joined on any condition. What are you trying to say? What does "null or missing" mean? What does "fields in the left query should return null" mean? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to say what you mean. Also act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it for an inner join and comment out all but one of the conditions, then uncomment them one at a time until the data disappears again - that's the faulty condition. If there was no data even with just one condition, that's the faulty condition:

```
SELECT 
    c.wc, 
    c.loc, 
    c.ord_no, 
    c.ser_lot_no, 
    c.line, 
    COALESCE(i.ItemNo, '') AS ItemNo, 
    COALESCE(i.BldSeqNo, '') AS BldSeqNo, 
    COALESCE(i.BldOrdNo, '') AS BldOrdNo, 
    COALESCE(i.StringItemNo, '') AS StringItemNo, 
    COALESCE(i.StringSerLotNo, '') AS StringSerLotNo, 
    MAX(c.InsertDateTime) AS LatestDateTime, 
    MIN(COALESCE(c.erp_transaction_id, 0)) AS MinimumErpID, 
    COALESCE(i.QtyOnHand, 0) AS QtyOnHand
FROM            
    dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data c 
    INNER JOIN dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil i
    ON  
      c.ser_lot_no = i.SerLotNo 
      --AND c.ord_no = i.OrderNo 
      --AND c.line = i.Bin
WHERE        
    ( c.erp_transaction_id < 3 OR c.erp_transaction_id IS NULL ) 
    AND (c.wc <> '') 
    AND (c.loc <> '') 
    AND (c.line <> '')
GROUP BY 
    c.wc, 
    c.loc, 
    c.ord_no, 
    c.ser_lot_no, 
    c.line, 
    COALESCE(i.ItemNo, ''), 
    COALESCE(i.BldSeqNo, '')
    COALESCE(i.BldOrdNo, '')
    COALESCE(i.StringItemNo, '')
    COALESCE(i.StringSerLotNo, '')
    COALESCE(i.QtyOnHand, 0)
ORDER BY c.ord_no DESC
```

Using INNER JOIN is more obvious than OUTER JOIN as most query tools give a row count and it's easier to see the row count changing from 99990 to 100000 than it is to eyeball 100000 rows looking for 10 that are null when they shouldn't be

If you have more than 2 tables, comment out your select block, put a *, and all but 2 tables:

```
SELECT *
 /* columns,list,here,blah,blah */
FROM
  table1
  JOIN table2 ON ...
  --JOIN table3 on ...
  --JOIN table4 on ...
```

Run it, get the expected number of rows, then proceed uncommenting more and more tables. If at any point your row count changes unexpectedly (more when you expected less, or less when you expected more) investigate.
If the row count increases, it's probably a cartesian product and should be resolved by adding extra join conditions, not by whacking a DISTINCT in

Other top tips:

- Use COALESCE rather than ISNULL; improve your database cross skilling
- Alias tables and use the alias name, rather than repeating the schema and column name everywhere
- GROUP BY the coalesced result rather than the column, if you're using a DB that draws a distinction between empty string and null string, otherwise you'll end up with two rows in your results when you expect 1

#### Edit: You said:

> Thank you for the insight and tips. However, my problem was more so a question on how to incorporate the information on which field was causing the join to fail as a permanent addition rather than a one time audit. Any insight for that? –

And I say:

You can't feasibly do this, the database cannot tell you "which field" isn't working out because most of them that aren't working out. To see what I mean, run this:

```
SELECT
  -- replace .id with the name of the pk column
  CONCAT('Cannot join c[', c.id, '] to i[', i.id, '] because: ',
    CASE 
      WHEN COALESCE(c.ser_lot_no, 'null') != COALESCE(i.SerLotNo, 'null ') THEN 'c.ser_lot_no != i.SerLotNo, '
    END,
    CASE 
      WHEN COALESCE(c.ord_no, 'null') != COALESCE(i.OrderNo, 'null ') THEN 'c.ord_no != i.OrderNo, '
    END,
    CASE 
      WHEN COALESCE(c.line, 'null') != COALESCE(i.Bin, 'null ') THEN 'c.line !=  i.Bin, '
    END
  )
FROM
dbo.cct_prod_plc_log_data c 
CROSS JOIN dbo.imlsmst_to_sfdtlfil i
```

It asks the database to join every row to every other row and then look at the values on the row and work out whether it can be joined or not.. If Table c has 1000 rows and table i has 2000 rows (and each row in c matches at most 2 rows in i), you'll get a result set of 2 million rows, 1998000 of which are "can't join this row to that row because..."

```
A.id
1
2
3

B.id
3
4
5
```

The only row from A that joins with B is "3", and even then "3" from A doesn't join with 4 or 5 from B, and 3 from B doesn't join with 1 or 2 from A. For your single set of matched rows, you have 8 complaints that the rows don't match (3x3 rows total, minus one match)

So no, you can't feasibly ask a database to tell you which rows from this table didn't match which rows from that table because of condition X, because the answer is "nearly all of them didn't match" and "all" could be hundreds of millions

It gets marginally more feasible if you have some join columns that should work out all the time, and others that sometimes don't:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.something != b.other THEN 'this row would fail because something != other' END 
FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id --and a.something = b.other
```

But think about it for a second; relational databases are centered around the idea that data is related, and you can even enforce it with constraints: "don't allow row X to be inserted here unless it has an A and a B and a C value that is present in this other table's D and E and F columns"

That's what you should be using to ensure your joins work out (relational integrity), not allowing any old crap into the database and then trying to work out which rows might have joined to which other rows if only there wasn't some typo in column A that meant it didn't quite match up with D, even though B/C matched with E/F ..

Comment: Thank you for the insight and tips. However, my problem was more so a question on how to incorporate the information on which field was causing the join to fail as a permanent addition rather than a one time audit.  Any insight for that?

Comment: The simple answer is no. For an explanation why, see my edit

Comment: Ok. Thank you for  the thought out answer. I will re-examine my design and see if I can get the result I want through that. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't something I was  missing.